# Why does it seem like the Capybara "wait for page to load" timer works for matchers but not finders?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm currently running a test that checks for a specific element and then do some stuff to it. The element takes a little for the javascript to finish kicking in, but well within the timer I've got Capybara set for.

For some reason

```
assert session.has_xpath?(xpath_route)
```

works fine, but

```
assert link=session.first(:xpath, xpath_route)
```

fails, saying it could not find the element. And quickly - long before the wait timer would run out.

I can only assume this means the timer only applies to matchers, not finders, which is fine, but how can I force it to keep looking until it finds the element I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct assuming that the timeout does not apply when using `first`. But you can use the `wait_until` method, which will keep retrying until either the timeout expires, or the block returns something truthy, so:

```
page.wait_until() do
  session.first(:xpath, xpath_route)
end
```

Comment: In Capybara v2.x the `page.wait_until` function has been removed. [rationale explained here](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara).